# What permissions are required to deploy a Dataiku project to an automation node?

Tags: dataiku

I'm the admin of my Dataiku design node and automation node and I can deploy projects. But now I want to allow some users to deploy certain projects and  although they can create bundles they can't publish it to the local deployer.

What permissions are required to allow users to deploy a project from Design node -> Local Deployer -> Automation node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are several permissions required for a successful deployment, in different nodes:

- On the Design node

  - The user need to have the permission "Create published projects", you give this permission by adding the user to a group with this permission.
  - Having this permission will enable the "Publish on Deployer" button on the Bundle object.
- On the Local Deployer

  - Projects > select the project > Settings > Permission give the user/group the "Deploy" permission (there are 4 permissions at the project level: View, Write, deploy, Admin).
  - Infrastructures > select the automation node > Settings > Permission, add the "Deploy" permission for the user/group (there are 3 permissions possible for infrastructure: View, Deploy, Admin)
  - With these two permissions the deploy button in the bundle will be enabled. But still the deploy will fail since unless the user has the right permission on the automation node.
- On the automation node

  - the user that is deploying need to have DESIGNER role on this node.
  - the user that is deploying need to have the "Admin" permission on that project (available project permissions Admin, Read project context, Write project content, Publish to data collections, Publish on workspaces, Export dataset, Read dashboard, Write dashboards, Run scenarios, Manage authorized objects, Manage shared objects)
  - This is documented on the [Dataiku REST API bundle for automation side](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/api/12/rest/#bundles,-automation-side), "Required privileges: ADMIN (on project)"